# CouchBD startkey and endkey issue

Tags: couchdb

I'm using couchDB and I have a problem trying to get the information that I want. Here's an example of my keys

```
[1,"Demo","March"]
[1,"Demo","May"]
[1, "No Demo", "May"]
```

I want to get all the keys that have "Demo" in the middle, I'm trying this:

```
http://localhost:PORT/database/_design/demo/_view/demoview?starkey=[{},"Demo",{}]&endkey=[{},"Demo",{}]
```

But I'm getting all the records, any idea?

Comment: `starkey` <> `startkey`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't,  sorry.  you can only ask for key ranges based on *prefix*, you can get the values between `[1, ...]` and `[999, "foo"]`, but you can't possibly write a query that will give you the values between `[..., "foo"]` and `[..., "bar"]`

For that, you need to write another view, one where the `"demo"` fragment appears first in the resulting keys.

Comment: Any further explanation on this?

Comment: @melaka: are you confused about something? I'm happy to elaborate on this answer if you can tell me where you're stuck

Comment: I posted a similar question, if you don't mind please have a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660997/couchdb-startkey-endkey-doesnt-filter-records-with-key-arrays-as-expected/25671235#25671235