# couchdb - startkey endkey doesn't filter records with key arrays as expected

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have Couch-DB map-reduce view which outputs this;

```
 {
rows: [
    {
        key: [
            "2014-08-20",
            2,
            "registration"
        ],
        value: 2
    },
    {
        key: [
            "2014-08-20",
            2,
            "search"
        ],
        value: 3
    },
    {
        key: [
            "2014-08-21",
            2,
            "registration"
        ],
        value: 3
    },
    {
        key: [
            "2014-08-21",
            2,
            "search"
        ],
        value: 4
    }
]
}
```

I need to query all the records that has between 2014-08-20 and 2014-08-21 Also the same time I need the integer value in the middle to be 2 and the last value to be "registration".

My curl request URL looks like this

```
BASE_URL?group=true&startkey=["2014-08-20",1,"registration"]
&endkey=["2014-08-21",1,"registration"]
```

This filters out the date but none of the other elements (the integer value and the string). Anyone got an idea whats happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

My Document structure looks something like this

```
[
    {
        platform_version: 2,
        UDID: "EWHSJeNp20sBFuzqcorkKVVi",
        session: {
            timestamp: "2014-08-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            session_id: "kOnNIhCNQ31LlkpEPQ7XnN1D",
            ip: "202.150.213.66",
            location: "1.30324,103.5498"
        },
        events: [
            {
                event_type: "search",
                timestamp: "2014-08-21T00:00:00.000Z",
                location: "1.30354,103.5301",
                attributes: {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        platform_version: 2,
        UDID: "EWHSJeNp20sBFuzqcorkKVVi",
        session: {
            timestamp: "2014-08-21T00:00:00.000Z",
            session_id: "kOnNIhCNQ31LlkpEPQ7XnN1D",
            ip: "202.150.213.66",
            location: "1.30324,103.5498"
        },
        events: [
            {
                event_type: "search",
                timestamp: "2014-08-21T00:00:00.000Z",
                location: "1.30354,103.5301",
                attributes: {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        platform_version: 2,
        UDID: "EWHSJeNp20sBFuzqcorkKVVi",
        session: {
            timestamp: "2014-08-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            session_id: "kOnNIhCNQ31LlkpEPQ7XnN1D",
            ip: "202.150.213.66",
            location: "1.30324,103.5498"
        },
        events: [
            {
                event_type: "click",
                timestamp: "2014-08-21T00:00:00.000Z",
                location: "1.30354,103.5301",
                attributes: {

                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and the map reduce function looks like this.

```
function(doc) {

date = doc.session.timestamp.split("T")[0];
eventArray = doc.events;
for (i = 0; i < eventArray.length; i++) { 

    emit([doc.app_version,eventArray[i].event_type,date],1);

}


}
```

It started working after I change the order of the keys. but still, I can't use a wildcard to query all the event types.

Comment: BASE_URL is a constant that I use to hold the URL to the couchdb server.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting documents with different second array item different then 1 because in the CouchDB the limits (`startkey` and `endkey`) are compared to map keys using [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). In the lexicographical order `[1,1] < [1,2] < [2,1] < [2,2]`.

What you need is either multidimensional queries (which are not supported by CouchDB), additional client-side filtering (which may increase data transferred between CouchDB and your app) or additional server-side filtering with [list function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions) (which increase processing time of queries).

If your app needs filtering using range only on the first element of key array (just like in your example query), you would solve your problem easily by placing the item at the last position of array, eg. emitting `[1, "registration", "2014-08-21"]` instead of `["2014-08-21", 1, "registration"]`.

Comment: Marcin - Thanks. What I need is to get all the records which says "registration" and the numarical value 1 between the days from 2014-08-20 and 2014-08-21. You think this is possible?

Comment: Marcin - also, It doesn't work when I want to use a wildcard on the middle string value, not even when I emit it as the last element.

Ex: 
startkey=[1, 0, "2014-08-20"]
&endkey=[1, {}, "2014-08-21"]

Comment: You can filter-out query result with list function.

Comment: Any other solution than using a list to query again?
Also is list function going to be faster than a separate PHP script that'll grab the map-reduce output and filter?

Comment: Problems which in general case are solved with multidimensional queries are difficult in CouchDB. Based on the specific use-case (eg. limitations on the expected data) usually you can have an efficient solution, possibly requiring changes in the data-structure (scheme for the documents). You did not provide any hints about your use-case, so I have no idea how to help you.

Comment: Updated my question. Hope that helps